# Is に acting like a を in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-を, passive-voice

> 私は、おまえ**に**、殺されにきた

I've seen this sentence for a while and the translation is something like "I'm going to kill you"(The context implies that too). But I don't understand why に (In bold) is being used and not を.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

殺され is passive.  As has been so kindly pointed out in the  comments, the sentence reads, "I came to be killed by you".

For a moment though, let's look at a slightly simpler sentence:

> 私は、おまえに、殺された

This sentence reads "I was killed by you".

In a passive sentence, the agent, the one who's actually doing something, is marked by に。

In order to get を in here, the passive needs to be eliminated completely

> おまえは私を殺した

> You killed me.

It looks like you might have thought the translation should be something like

> I came to kill you.

in that case, the Japanese should have read

> 私はおまえを殺しにきた

Notice the important difference between 殺し and 殺され.  The difference is the first is an *active* voice and the second is *passive*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this sentence isn't interchangeable with を at all?

Comment: @Artsuhtaraz, no, not interchangeable without changing the verb and the grammar of the sentence.  Passive: 私はお前[に]{●}殺される.  Active: お前は私[を]{●}殺す.  Think of the に as a bit like "by" in the English passive construction, used to mark the agent (the doer of the action) of the passive verb: 私はお前[に]{●}殺される → I am killed **by** you.  Meanwhile, を has no English analog -- English expresses the object simply by the syntax (the ordering of the parts of a sentence).

Comment: A.Ellett, a minor point, but I believe the person that きた is the 私, not the おまえ: _"I came to be killed by you."_

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thank you for the corrections.